# Fill missing values on a table

Tags: java, mysql, r, jdbc

I have a list of dates and prices:

```
Date           Price
1/3/2000        10.00
1/5/2000        10.45
1/7/2000        10.25
...               ...
```

I have a separate list of dates with all dates:

```
Date
1/1/2000
1/2/2000
1/3/2000
...
```

I need to have them combined so that the prior price is filled in for the dates that are missing prices:

```
Date            Price
1/1/2000         10.00
1/2/2000         10.00
1/3/2000         10.00
1/4/2000         10.00
1/5/2000         10.45
1/6/2000         10.45
1/7/2000         10.25
...               ...
```

I am currently trying to loop through array lists holding the data but can't line the dates up correctly, especially at the beginning and end. I am using Java/Mysql/JDBC right now but am open to R also.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for your help.  Here's what I ended up doing:
-I created a list of all indexes where the dates matched.
-I then inserted the prices into an array with the same number of elements as the full time list.
-I then created 3 loops, one for the elements before the first matching time, one for the elements after the last matching element and finally one for everything in between.
-These three filled in the prices that were missing.

Just though I'd share.  Thanks for all your help.

```
public static void checkLengths(ArrayList<String> masterTimes, ArrayList<String> testTimes, ArrayList<Double> prices){
    ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Integer> matches = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Double[] temp2 = new Double [masterTimes.size()];
    int mt = masterTimes.size();
    int tt = testTimes.size();
        if(mt == tt){
            return;
        }else{
            int mast = 0;
            int test = 0;
            String mt1 = masterTimes.get(0);
            String tt1 = testTimes.get(0);

            test = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < masterTimes.size(); i++){
                mt1 = masterTimes.get(i);
                tt1 = testTimes.get(test);
                System.out.println(" | mt1: " + mt1 + " | tt1: " + tt1);
                    if(mt1.equals(tt1)){
                        matches.add(i);
                        System.out.println("Inserting: " + i);
                        if(test < testTimes.size()){
                        test++;
                        }
                        if(test == testTimes.size()){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            }
            System.out.println("Matches:");
            printAL(matches);

            // puts in known prices.
            for(int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++){
                int g = matches.get(i);
                temp2[g] =  prices.get(i);
            }

            System.out.println("FirstPrices:");
            printAR(temp2);

            // Finds index of first and last matching times.
            int matcher1 = matches.get(0);
            int ind = matches.size() - 1;
            int matcher2 = matches.get(ind);
            System.out.println("Matcher1:" + matcher1 + " | Matcher2: " + matcher2);

            // If a price is empty/null, it puts the prior price in it.
            for(int i = matcher1; i < matcher2; i ++){
                System.out.println(i + " | " + temp2[i]);
                if(temp2[i] == null){
                    System.out.println(temp2[i] + " | " + temp2[i-1]);
                    temp2[i] = temp2[i-1];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("SecondPrices:");
            printAR(temp2);

            // Deals with start.
            for(int i = matcher1; i >= 0; i--){
                if(temp2[i] == null){
                    temp2[i] = temp2[i+1];
                }
            }

            System.out.println("ThirdPrices:");
            printAR(temp2);

            // Deals with end.
            for(int i = matcher2; i < temp2.length; i++){
                if(temp2[i] == null){
                    temp2[i] = temp2[i-1];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("FourthPrices:");
            printAR(temp2);             

            prices.clear();
            System.out.println("Final Check:");

            for (int i = 0; i < masterTimes.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(i + " | " + masterTimes.get(i) + " | " + temp2[i]);
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help without looking at the code but it seems like your indexes are not matching up or something is wrong with your looping logic.

Consider using a HashTable or a HashMap using the date strings as keys and price as values.

Loop through your date range one day at a time look up the price in the HashTable, if not found then use the previous price.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I just shooting at it while being on the fon :)

In MySQL, let's assume you got two tables, dates_prices and all_dates. Then LEFT JOIN them on dates and order them by date.

If you use R and MySQL you can use the RMySQL package to load the resulting table to R. 
In R you can convert the dates to POSIX with `as.POSIXlt`. You also might want to use the `lag`function in R (but I am not sure yet if that helps with lags of varying spans).

Apart from that you could use R's ´sqldf` package if you want to try with "plain" R but want to use SQL functionality. If you post some reproducible code to set up the data.. I could try to the give something more concrete back.

EDIT:

The `impute` package might be what you really looking for... see also [here](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/S/Harrell/help/Hmisc/html/impute.html)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem does take a bit of doing to do correctly. Sometimes using a flow chart helps if you get stuck.

Try using the following sample code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FillDates
{
    public static void fillUnknownDates(Connection c) throws SQLException
    {
        // Loads in a Vector of Strings of all the dates
        Statement state = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = state.executeQuery("SELECT d FROM Dates ORDER BY d;");
        Vector<String> dates = new Vector<String>();
        while (results.next())
        {
            dates.add(results.getString("d"));
        }

        // Load in a list of all date/price combinations
        Vector<DatePrice> pairs = new Vector<DatePrice>();
        state = c.createStatement();
        results = state.executeQuery("SELECT d, p FROM DatePrices ORDER BY d;");
        while (results.next())
        {
            pairs.add(new DatePrice(results.getString("d"), results.getString("p")));
        }

        // Now go through the two lists and add missing prices
        state = c.createStatement();
        int dateIndex = 0;
        DatePrice last = pairs.get(0), current;
        for (int pairIndex = 1; pairIndex < pairs.size(); pairIndex++)
        {
            current = pairs.get(pairIndex);
            while (dateIndex < dates.size() && dates.get(dateIndex).compareTo(current.getDate()) < 0)
            {
                // Batch things up so it takes less time to run
                state.addBatch("INSERT INTO DatePrices VALUES (\""+dates.get(dateIndex)+"\", \""+current.getPrice+"\");");
                dateIndex ++;
            }

            last = current;
        }
        state.executeBatch();
    }

    // A convenience class
    public static class DatePrice
    {
        private String date, price;

        public DatePrice(String date, String price)
        {
            this.date = date;
            this.price = price;
        }
        public String getDate()
        {
            return date;
        }
        public String getPrice()
        {
            return price;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it's not complete, and you'll need to change the names of your tables and columns before trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an R solution.

Uncomment the two `install.packages` lines if you don't have those packages already installed.  Also `textConnection(Lines1)` and `textConnection(Lines2)` are just to keep the example self contained and in reality would be replaced with something like `"myfile1.dat"` and `"myfile2.dat"` assuming the data is in those files.

It reads in the data creating zoo object `z` and a Date vector `dt`.  It then merges `z` with a zero width zoo object (i.e. it has dates but no data) whose date index is made from `dt`.  `na.locf` (last observation carried forward) fills out the missing values in reverse order since `fromLast = TRUE`

```
Lines1 <- "Date           Price
1/3/2000        10.00
1/5/2000        10.45
1/7/2000        10.25"

Lines2 <- "Date
1/1/2000
1/2/2000
1/3/2000"

# install.packages("zoo")
# install.packages("chron")
library(zoo)
library(chron)
z <- read.zoo(textConnection(Lines1), header = TRUE, FUN = as.chron)
dt <- as.chron(scan(textConnection(Lines2), skip = 1, what = ""))
na.locf(merge(z, zoo(, dt)), fromLast = TRUE)
```

The result is:

```
> na.locf(merge(z, zoo(, dt)), fromLast = TRUE)
01/01/00 01/02/00 01/03/00 01/05/00 01/07/00 
   10.00    10.00    10.00    10.45    10.25
```

There are three vignettes (PDF documents) that come with the [zoo package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) and [R News 4/1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf) Help Desk article has info and references on dates.